# jquery calculate output with 2 decimals

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the output result working with 2 decimals always displaying, even if it's 1+4 (with no decimals) it should be 5.00

However, it's not working. It just shows the result always without decimals. Pretty sure I am putting the .toFixed in the wrong place, but where? I tried pretty much everywhere ...

```
$("#amount1").keyup(calc);
$("#amount2").keyup(calc);

function calc() {

    $('#result').html(
        parseFloat($('#amount1').val(), 10) + parseFloat($("#amount2").val(), 10)
    ).toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: The `toFix` should be called on the float, not on the results of the call to `html`.

Comment: Tried that but then for some reason it shows 2.00 plus 4.00 as "2.004.00".

Comment: Can you provide a [minimum complete verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `(parseFloat($('#amount1').val(), 10) + parseFloat($("#amount2").val(), 10)).toFixed(2)`

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rny5g6og/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#amount1").keyup(calc);
    $("#amount2").keyup(calc);

    function calc() {
        var a = parseFloat($('#amount1').val(), 10);
        var b = parseFloat($('#amount2').val(), 10);
        $('#result').html(
            (a + b).toFixed(2)
        );
    }
});
```